# Using json.loads() on data returned from Zoho Creator - extra_data() error

Tags: python, json, python-requests, zoho

I get the following return from zoho creators api:

```
'var zohoview6 = {"Name_Registration":[     {"Approved":"Yes","Extension":1197,"ID_Number":"","Email":"xxx@yy.com","name_first  ":"Test","Updated":false,"ID":"1257609000000083070","Authorised":true,"NameID":68       }]};'
```

I then use str.replace to remove 'var zohoview6 = '

However, when I load the resulting str using json.loads(str) I get the following error

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 192 - line 1 column 193 (char 191 - 192)
```

Here's the return I get formatted nicely:

```
var zohoview6 = 
{
    "Name_Registration":[
        {
        "Approved":"Yes",
        "Extension":1197,
        "ID_Number":"",
        "Email":"xxx@yy.com",
        "name_first":"Test",
        "Updated":false,
        "ID":"1257609000000083070",
        "Authorised":true,
        "NameID":68
        }]
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to remove the extra `;` at the end of the string using, for instance, [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip):

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> s = 'var zohoview6 = {"Name_Registration":[     {"Approved":"Yes","Extension":1197,"ID_Number":"","Email":"xxx@yy.com","name_first  ":"Test","Updated":false,"ID":"1257609000000083070","Authorised":true,"NameID":68       }]};'
>>> data = s.replace("var zohoview6 = ", "").rstrip(";")
>>> json.loads(data)
{u'Name_Registration': [{u'Updated': False, u'Extension': 1197, u'ID_Number': u'', u'Email': u'xxx@yy.com', u'Authorised': True, u'name_first  ': u'Test', u'ID': u'1257609000000083070', u'NameID': 68, u'Approved': u'Yes'}]}
```